# @fullcalendar/google-calendar breaks with 'gatsby build'

Tags: node.js, webpack, fullcalendar, gatsby, fullcalendar-5

@fullcalendar/google-calendar seems to try to fetch JSON during the static gatsby build. I am unsure where to start looking.

When running `gatsby build` on my project the build breaks with the following error:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.026s
error Building static HTML failed for path "/calendar/"

  6431 |         body = encodeParams(params);
  6432 |     }
> 6433 |     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       | ^
  6434 |     xhr.open(method, url, true);
  6435 |     if (method !== 'GET') {
  6436 |         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
  
  - main.js:6433 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6433:1
  
  - main.js:54 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/google-calendar/main.js:54:24
  
  - main.js:6199 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6199:1
  
  - main.js:6187 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6187:1
  
  - main.js:6170 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6170:1
  
  - main.js:6162 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6162:1
  
  - main.js:6113 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6113:1
  
  - main.js:6928 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:6928:1
  
  - main.js:7306 
    node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:7306:1
```

The page is defined as follows:

```
import React from "react"

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar
    plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
    googleCalendarApiKey='XXX'
    height="100vh"
    eventSources= {[
    {
          googleCalendarId: 'en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
      color: '#1f78b4'
        }
    ]}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to create an executable test case, but am very happy to receive advice. Any pointers on how I can make this work would be highly appreciated.

Using @loadable works both for build and develop versions.

```
import React from "react"
import loadable from '@loadable/component'

const OtherComponent = loadable(() => import('../components/calendar.js'))
function MyComponent() {
  return (
      <OtherComponent />
  )
}

export default function Home() {
  return <MyComponent />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@fullcalendar\/google-calendar/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Some [third-party dependencies use some global objects like `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) to make their stuff. This is perfectly valid when running `gatsby develop` since the code is compiled on the browser-side. However, `gatsby build` occurs in the server-side (your Node server) where obviously no window, because it's not even already defined yet.

That's why you need to add a `null` loader to the webpack's config by calling the [`onCreateWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/) API, to avoid the dependency transpilation on the server-side.

The rule is a regular expression (that's why is between slashes) and literally, the `test` value matches a path in your `node_modules` folder to look for the dependency location, so, you must put there the exact folder name, I've assumed that is `@fullcalendar/google-calendar` but you have some potential folders that may create the conflict too:

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';
```

Using [`@loadable/component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loadable/component):

```
import React from "react"
import loadable from '@loadable/component'

const OtherComponent = loadable(() => import('../components/calendar.js'))
function MyComponent() {
  return (
      <OtherComponent />
  )
}

export default function Home() {
  return <MyComponent />
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ferran for the immediate reply. Unfortunately, this brings me only to the following error:

```
  5351 |     function addDefs(defs) {
> 5352 |         for (var _i = 0, defs_1 = defs; _i < defs_1.length; _i++) {

  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js:5352:40
```

I am somehow lost. Why would @fullcalendar try to fetch calendar content while building the static pages. I somehow lack the context why this could/would be needed?

Comment: Because it's how webpack's acts in the building process. Sometimes, the bad module is not the library itself, is one of the dev-dependencies. You can try to use loadable-components: https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components

Comment: Loadable components prevented the 'gatsby build' failure and make 'gatsby serve' deliver a usable website. So the major problem is resolved. Thanks a lot!
However, 'gatsby develop' now shows an empty page rather than the calendar. Is this expected or is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: It's not expected. Loadable, summarizing, only bypass the SSR and transport it to the browser-side, avoiding the major issue, but it should work in `gatsby develop.` Can you upgrade the question with the new code?

Comment: I tried this again using a clean gatsby started and 'gatsby develop' works as well. No idea what is broken in my setup, but it seems independent of this particular issue. I guess this means I can resolve this question. I inlined my solution in the question. Feel free to copy it into your answer.